# Djangorest framework same Generic Create View with GET and POST

Tags: python, django, url, django-rest-framework, http-verbs

I'm using a Generic CreateAPIView to save a model in the database. Here's my code:

```
class AppointmentCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (AppointmentCreatePermission,)
    queryset = Appointment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AppointmentSerializer
```

And in my `urls.py` file, I have this:

```
urlpatterns[
    url(r'^appointments/create', AppointmentCreateAPIView.as_view()),
]
```

This url obviously supports the POST operation. However, I want to use this same url to handle a GET request, which would fetch the data necessary to populate the appointment creation form. I understand that I can use separate urls for get and post, but that's not what I'm looking for. Is it possible that I keep the same url, but with different HTTP Verb, the view would be able to handle both GET and POST request?

Comment: Do you get any error when using `GET` method

Comment: I'm ready to change my logic, but I want to keep the url the same. Is it possible to call two different views with the same url, but with different http verb?

Comment: I think that's not possible. Different url but same function is possible but in your case GET method completely off by design.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by manually adding `get` method to your view, it would look something like this. Code below probably will not work, but will give you general idea.

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

class AppointmentCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (AppointmentCreatePermission,)
    queryset = Appointment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AppointmentSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = AppointmentSerializer({your_data})
        return Response(serializer.data)
```